# I'm trying to create a discord bot with commands that only work with the right permissions. When I tried it, I came across an erorr

Tags: javascript

```
  if(command.permissions.length){
    let invalidPerms = []
    for(const perm of command.permissions){
      if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
        return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
      }
      if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
        invalidPerms.push(perm);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (invalidPerms.length){
      return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
    }
  }
```

Error: ReferenceError: command is not defined Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? I checked all the code I have and it seems right.

main.js Code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');
const event_handler = require('./handlers/event_handler');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})


client.login('Discord Login ID');
```

event handler code

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const load_dir = (dirs) =>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client))
        }
    }
    
    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));

}
```

command handler code

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command); 
        }   else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

message guild code

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) =>{
    const prefix = '-';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd= args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

^Thats with the command permissions

Added more of my code. Can anyone find the error? All of the code looks right, I checked again and all spelling is correct. You could check again but I think the it has to do with the code and not the spelling.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code? Right now, the variable "command" is not defined.

Comment: Just added more of my code. Feel free to check it out and find an error so I can fix that.

Comment: Which file is that top bit of code in?

Comment: messageCreate.js is with the top bit of the code and the last bit of the code.

Comment: Could you tell me on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `command` is defined inside the module export, and cannot be referenced in that top bit of code.

Comment: How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: You need to define command where it can be accessible. Depending on what your bot does, that could be done different ways. "let command =..." At the top of your first code snippet.

Comment: Or just move that top code into that bottom module export, below "const command = ..."

Comment: Okay I moved the top code below module export like this. And got an error  message is not defined. https://srcshare.io/?id=622053512370934bb6a19e5c Code of that can be found at the link.

I tried the other way with "let command =" and got  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). Link to the code to see: https://srcshare.io/?id=62205391237093a490a19e5e

Comment: This really isn't the appropriate forum for this level of assistance. You are clearly a beginner programer, and you really just need to learn what you are doing. This is the last thing I will say: Command is not defined. You need to define command in EVERY file you reference it. That means you need a const command ... / let command ... / var command ... at the top of that first code block. You also neeed to replace the "..." with correct value of command. IDK what that is because IDK your program.